# How to adapt PATH variable in Makefile.am?

Tags: makefile, path, configure, automake

In the file `Makefile.am` a am using somehting like this:

```
PATH := $(PWD)/.tools/bin:$(PATH)
```

When running `configure.ac` I get this error:

```
Makefile.am:3: warning: ':='-style assignments are not portable
```

I using the assignment operator `=` would cause a recursive problem.

So I wonder how to adapt PATH variable in Makefile.am without having this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If I really needed to change the shell's PATH inside a rule, I would set a *shell* variable `PATH` there, not a *make* variable `PATH`:

```
foo.h: foo.src
        PATH="$${PATH}:$$(pwd)/.tools/bin"; \
        my-tool foo.src > foo.h
```

However, if I need `my-tool` from that directory, why not call `my-tool` with the proper path in the first place?

```
foo.h: foo.src .tools/bin/my-tool
        ./.tools/bin/my-tool foo.src > foo.h
```